# Call a function after vertical scroll bar of body arrives

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a parent table,

1. After clicking the checkbox of parent table a child table will generate,then
2. After clicking that child table's checkbox  another child table will generate,
   at that time a vertical scroll bar will come to the body and horizontal scroll bar will show on all tables.

I want to hide all horizontal scroll bar of tables when vertical scroll bar of body is visible.

Comment: window.onload should do...

Comment: post your code in fiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can detect if scroll bars is applied to an element or not, using JS.

```
var _html = document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0],
    _htmlHeight = _html .clientHeight,
    _htmlScrollHeight = _html.scrollHeight,
    _scrollbar = false;

if(_htmlScrollHeight > _htmlHeight) {
    _scrollbar = true;
}
```

You can wrap this in a function and call on checkbox click. If scrollbar is applied to your body - `_scrollbar` will be true. Then you can add some class and hide your table scrollbars.

If you need more precise solution - post your code buddy!